# Program to burn .iso file into a watchable DVD

Tags: iso-image

What's a good program to burn an iso file that contains an AUDIO_TS AND VIDEO_TS folder into a watchable DVD that a DVD player should handle.

I tried using ImgBurn but that didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Have yu any Image reader software like Daemon, Magic ISO which can mount the `.iso` image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a valid ISO file, you should have no problem burning it regardless of the contents.

OS X and Ubuntu come with ISO burning software. With Windows, it depends on which version you have. Windows 7 can also [natively burn](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/windowsexperience/archive/2009/04/13/burn-iso-images-natively-in-windows-7.aspx) ISO files, while prior versions needed additional software. If you Google for "Windows ISO Burners", there will be many results for decent software. I've personally used [Active ISO Burner](http://download.cnet.com/Active-ISO-Burner/3000-2646_4-10602452.html), it's free and simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

You might find my [program](http://scsi.codeplex.com/) helpful, as well as [CD-R Tools Front-end](http://cdrtfe.sourceforge.net/cdrtfe/index_en.html).